# How to say 104th in German?

Tags: numbers

I wonder how to write the ordinal number 104 in German. Is it 'hundertvier**te**' or 'hundertvier**ste**'?

Answer (score 1):

It would be "hundertundvierte".
Source: Dudenband 4, Ausgabe 2009, S.388.

The rule is simple: If the numbers 1 to 19 (inclusive) are part of the number, then you use -t.

```
+--------+-----------------------+
| Number |  Written out number   |
+--------+-----------------------+
|    10  | zehnte.               |
|    19  | neunzehnte.           |
|    20  | zwanzigste.           |
|    21  | einundzwanzigste.     |
|    99  | neunundneunzigste.    |
|   100  | hundertste.           |
|   102  | hundertundzweite.     |
|   110  | hundertundzehnte.     |
|   119  | hundertundneunzehnte. |
|   120  | hundertundzwanzigste. |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

... watch out for 1, which is "erste". `hundertunderste`. Alternatively, `hundertundeinte` is okay too. "Ein" has a lot of irregularities.

Comment: I think I get it, but now I'm confused. Because in Duden dictionary I see both variants 'hunderteins' and 'hundertundeins'. But it's 'hundertzechn, hundertachtzig' (without und)

Comment: @DarinaFilipova "und" is only mandatory as a connection between tens and ones. It is not used between thousands and hundreds, and is optional between hundreds and ones. "Hundertundzehn" must be correct, too. My guess is that Duden is listing the most commonly used versions of these numbers, and for "eins", "und" may be preferred. 
Anyone who knows more, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Do you have a source for "hundertundeinte"?

Comment: @CarstenS Same source as in my original answer.